# Extended Reports Bug?

Tags: civireport, extension, custom-reports

I have recently installed the [Extended Reports Extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) within civiCRM. However, I am noticing some strange behavior when I attempt to make a template.

Within the Bookkeeping with extra fields template, if I use the group by function, I do not receive the proper line totals (they are not adding up).

For instance, if I group by line item financial type, it groups it correctly, but the line totals are wrong: 
[image: bookkeeping group by line item]

If I use the Contribution Based Line Item report, the totals are accurate. However, I need the account code on this report, which is why I was using the bookkeeping report. 
[image: line item report]

Any idea on how to fix this or make the account codes available in the Contribution Based Report? I looked through the code and was able to make the financial account columns appear; however, upon selecting the columns I got a "DB not available error". I believe I need to add something similar to the code below, but I wasn't exactly sure how to do it correctly.

```
function joinActivityFromCase() {
$this->_from .= "
  LEFT JOIN {$this->_caseActivityTable} cca ON cca.case_id = {$this->_aliases['civicrm_case']}.id
  LEFT JOIN civicrm_activity {$this->_aliases['civicrm_activity']} ON {$this->_aliases['civicrm_activity']}.id = cca.activity_id";
}
```

I couldn't find a place to report the bug on civiCRM, so I posted it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With most extensions, the place to report bugs is on Github. In this case you want to go to https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport and click on the "Issues" tab at the top.

Comment: I also ran into the same problem of not knowing where to place a bug report on this extension.  Perhaps an extra line on the extension page to this effect is in order?

Answer (score 3):

See also  https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting but take a look at [the question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17286/bug-reports-and-feedback) I am just about to post in case you're interested in civiCRM.org/higher level bug reporting and feedback