# Bug reports and feedback

Tags: issues

I'm not sure where/how to offer user-level bug reports and feedback on my experience using the civiCRM.org web site itself to evaluate and learn civi.

I am aware of  https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting and the github site for reporting faults in civi itself, but I have a couple of UX feedback points and bug reports to offer, arising from just signing up to newsletters etc.

Thanks, and be gentle, I'm a newbie, hope this is not an uber-daft question!

Answer (score 1):

If you have feedback about the civicrm.org site itself, you can give that feedback by one of a few routes:
* You can submit a JIRA issue on the "INFRA" project, rather than the "CRM" project, which tracks the software itself.
* You can raise the issue on https://chat.civicrm.org, in the "infrastructure" channel.

If the issues you're raising are due to UX issues in CiviCRM itself, you can submit those via JIRA.  That said - given that resources for any project are limited, simply submitting an issue to JIRA is unlikely to move it forward very far.  It's better to submit an issue than not to though!